# Responding to ViewPager2 Fragments Events in Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I have a main activity that contains a ViewPager2 and a TabLayout to house a few fragments. Each fragment will have buttons that I want to trigger actions in the main activity. However, I'm not seeing how to set up the buttons/event handlers so that the main activity is notified whenever a button is pressed inside one of the fragments. Thanks!

**MenuActivity.kt - ViewPager2/TabLayout Setup**

```kotlin
private fun configureMenu() {
        // Create adapter
        val fragmentAdapter = PageAdapter(supportFragmentManager, lifecycle)
        // Add fragments
        fragmentAdapter.addFragment(CameraFragment(), getString(R.string.camera_tab))
        fragmentAdapter.addFragment(DevicesFragment(), getString(R.string.devices_tab))
        fragmentAdapter.addFragment(ConnectionFragment(), getString(R.string.connection_tab))
        // Set up pageviewer
        viewpager_menu.adapter = fragmentAdapter
        TabLayoutMediator(tablayout_main, viewpager_menu) { tab, position ->
            tab.text = fragmentAdapter.getPageTitle(position)
            viewpager_menu.setCurrentItem(tab.position, true)
        }.attach()
}
```

**PageAdapter.kt**

```kotlin
class PageAdapter(fm: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle): FragmentStateAdapter(fm, lifecycle) {

    private var fragmentList = ArrayList<Fragment>()
    private var fragmentTitleList = ArrayList<String>()

    fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, title: String) {
        fragmentList.add(fragment)
        fragmentTitleList.add(title)
    }

    override fun onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return fragmentList.size
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return fragmentList[position]
    }

    fun getPageTitle(position: Int): String {
        return fragmentTitleList[position]
    }
}
```

**CameraFragment.kt**

```kotlin
class CameraFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false)
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside actions of the fragment

```
val main = this.activity!! as MainActivity
main.callSomeFunc()
```

Comment: What's self? Returns an error in the fragment

Comment: Does have to be in the `onViewCreated`, though, so the fragment knows that layout

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the this object of activity in specific frament constructor and use from fragment to call the activity class method

for example:

```
 class MenuActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    fragmentAdapter.addFragment(CameraFragment(this), getString(R.string.camera_tab))

}

  class CameraFragment : Fragment {
        var mActivity: MenuActivity? = null
        constructor(mActivity: MenuActivity?) {
            this.mActivity = mActivity
        }

        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false)
            
            onlick{
                mActivity.callMethodOfMenuActivity()
            }
        }
    }
```